# Where to place external python scripts in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Where someone should place any external python script for her Django project? What is the more appropriate location (if any)? Shall she create a folder in the main Django project and put it there and add this to the python path or is there a better way to deal with this issue? The reason for external scripts is not to overload the views with code that can be better organized in script files and can serve more than one views.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a folder, say utils, and make it a module by creating `__init__.py` inside it.
Now create any script under this folder. Let's say you have a file called utils.py that contains some of your python code and you want to import it.

Wherever you want to import then import your python script like

```py
from utils.utils import YourClassOrFunction
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have additional files that have generic code in their own files and just import them when you need them for your views, or whatever. If they are only going to be used in one app, then just put them in that apps folder. If they are more generic then you can put them in a file or folder that isn't part of any particular app.

Django does some magic with files and folders it expects to exist, but you can put other files wherever you want it works like any other Python project.

Comment: I did that and when I added the python script in the main project folder and tried to import from the Django interactive python shell it worked, but when I created a folder there and placed inside the script this was not discovered. So how can I declare this folder. Just add it to the python path and thats it or is it a better way to go?

Comment: If you place them in a  folder you need to add a file called `__init__.py` to the folder. It can be empty. After that you should be able to import files from the folder.

Comment: Thank you very much! Correct answer but I read first `@gamer`' s answer which is also correct so marked him as correct and you gave an up vote.... Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Adding project path should be done at your `manage.py`, but if you wanted to do something before your request reached `views.py` you can use `middlewares`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/